# Validate that an IP address is in fact a website with Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm wondering if it is possible to check whether an IP address is tied to a website (rather than say someone's XBox). A simplified explanation of what I am trying to do is generate a random IP and point the browser to it. If it's not a website, go on to the next IP.
Thoughts?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: @lwburk: why not?  sounds like fun.

Comment: 2 Billion + addresses - might take a while.  Also not sure the military will really like you pinging lots and lots of their machines!

Comment: Also, many servers (with 1 IP) host a number of different websites. The IP address of that server will often _not_ resolve to an actual website, since there isn't any useful host information.

Answer (score 2):

If jQuery is an option for you the following would work

```
var ip = ...;
var uri = "http://" + ip + ":80";
$.get(uri)
  .success(function () { validIp(ip); })
  .error(function () { invalidIp(ip); });
```

Note: This will only tell you though that

- ip **was** a valid http address at some point in the past.  It's suggestive of the future but by no means definitive
- Only works for websites that return a default page on port 80

This will certainly ring true for a subset of valid web pages out there.  But it will also report an error for many IPs which do contain a valid web server.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely it's not possible. Directly sending an request would be denied by the crossdomain policies of the browsers.

You could try to implement something using an img tag or something like that and listening for the onload event. But the only way to be sure there is something behind port 80 is to request it from a backend server and send the test result back to your javascript frontend.

Answer (score 0):

No, but, is basically the answer.

For a start the vast majority of IP addresses they handle multiple sites so simply pointing your browser to an IP address will often give you a default error page, its only if you request a site that you will recieve a useful response. You could simply see if it handles HTTP traffic (port 80) but I dont think that is what your after.

Comment: Is there a way to view the websites hosted on an IP address?

Answer (score 0):

If the IP address accepts connections on port 80 and issues a valid HTTP response in response to a valid HTTP request, then it's a website.  You could, for example, attempt to connect to port 80 of the IP address and when connected print the following string:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: [ip address here]
```

If you get an HTTP response then yes, it's a website!

However, if you're trying to do this from a web browser then you might be out of luck due to the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) (although you could do some sneaky things with images or script tags by using the IP address as the src attribute and having your "onload" handler indicate success/failure).

Answer (score 0):

You could use JS to send an HTTP Request and see if it sends back a Response. That would indicate if an HTTP server is running at that machine. Would this help ?